# How to extract test cases from test plan in ALM 12.2 to Excel

Tags: hp-alm-12.20

I need to extract the test cases from test plan to excel.
Please can you help me in providing the sql to do this.

Test name, Test description, Step name, Step description, Expected result from specific folder of a test plan needs to extracted to excel.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789224/export-hp-alm-test-plan-to-an-excel-file

Answer (score 1):

Try this query, hope it helps:

```
Select TS_TEST_ID as "Test ID",TS_NAME as "Test Case Name",TS_DESCRIPTION as
"Test Description",DS_STEP_ORDER as "Step#",DS_STEP_NAME as "Step Name",
DS_DESCRIPTION as "Step Description",DS_EXPECTED as "Expected Results", 
TS_RESPONSIBLE as "Test Case Designer" from  DESSTEPS 
inner join TEST on DS_TEST_ID = TS_TEST_ID where TS_SUBJECT = 1218  
/* TS_Subject is the folder ID*/
```